# Задать паттерн для строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, парсер

Просьба подсказать как можно добавить паттерн для парсера/метода для строки
примеры:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
list.add('0456-5-1-3-060323');
list.add('0370-10-2-3-020323-П'); 
list.add('0369-10-020423-П');
list.add('03.01.08');
```

Метод должен работать так, чтобы я на выходе мог получить лист только с индексами 0, 1, 2.

есть похожий парсер для строки '03.01.08'

```java
public List<String> getCode(String document) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(document);

    List<String> codeList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        int size = matcher.group().length();
        if (size > 3 && size != 10) {
            codeList.add(matcher.group());
        }
    }

    return codeList;
}
```

Comment: Что должен делать парсер с представленными данными?  Сопоставлять строки целиком или по частям?  Постарайтесь объяснить вашу задачу.

Comment: @Nowhere Man я поменял описание задачи, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно отфильтровать строки в списке, можно использовать `String::matches` как функци-предикат в потоке строк.

В простейшем случае формат может быть такой:
`"\\d{4}(-\\d{1,2}){1,3}(-\\d{6})(-\\p{Lu})?"`

- в начале строки 4 цифры;
- затем от 1 до 3 групп, начинающихся с минуса и содержащих 1 или 2 цифры;
- группа из минуса и 6 цифр ровно
- группа из минуса и любой заглавной буквы

Возможно, для отдельных групп цифр следует использовать дополнительные ограничения, типа проверки даты в `ddmmyy` формате, где дни должны быть в диапазоне `01-31`, месяцы - `01-12` и т.п.

```java
public static List<String> filterData(List<String> data) {
    return data.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.matches("\\d{4}(-\\d{1,2}){1,3}(-\\d{6})(-\\p{Lu})?"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

Если нужно распарсить некую строку, содержащую данные в указанном формате, разделённые произвольными разделителями, можно применить паттерн и получить поток строк при помощи `Matcher::results`:

```java
public static List<String> filterString(String str) {
    return Pattern.compile("\\d{4}(-\\d{1,2}){1,3}(-\\d{6})(-\\p{Lu})?")
        .matcher(str)
        .results()
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Тест:

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
    "0456-5-1-3-060323", "0370-10-2-3-020323-П", "0369-10-020423-П","03.01.08"
);

System.out.println(filterData(list));

String str = "0456-5-1-3-060323; 0370-10-2-3-020323-П, 0369-10-020423-П  03.01.08";

System.out.println(filterString(str));
```

Результаты:

```
[0456-5-1-3-060323, 0370-10-2-3-020323-П, 0369-10-020423-П]
[0456-5-1-3-060323, 0370-10-2-3-020323-П, 0369-10-020423-П]
```